# How to attach vent flashing

Tags: waterproofing, roofing, flashing, shingles

I have installed b-vent flashing on my roof which is at at 9/12 slope. I sank nails along the left, right, and top edges that are under the shingles.  However, I'm debating if I want to attach the bottom edge.  Whether I use gasket screws or nails, I feel it's just making a few additional holes that could potentially leak and that aren't very necessary.  The flashing seems sturdily affixed without them and I don't really think water is going to back upwards.
I've seen both attached and unattached b-vent flashing.  Could I have suggestions as to which is better and why?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am a firm believer of not nailing the exposed parts of flashing.

I do add roofing tar or other sealant under the flashing.

Normally if the roof slope is 3/12 or greater there is little chance of rain getting under the flashing. Wind driven rain could be an issue, but if sealed properly it is normally minimal or nil.

Comment: If I seal the exposed edge, do you think it's possible errant water and moisture could build up behind it because there would be no place for it to drain out?

Comment: if everything is done properly, ( the flashing the shingles) there will be no water behind or under the flashing.